# Identify what is happening to my app in android samsung galaxy tab

Tags: android, screen, emulation

i installed my app in samsung galaxy tab. but the view is not fitting to the whole screen. it is working fine in small devices.. what is the reason? see image below
[image]

Comment: Whats your sdk version for this app ?

Comment: @ Chirag Raval yes..but i updated to 2.2 by changing the project property

Comment: please change your minimum sdk version in your manifest file to 8 and then again run the application

Comment: I am also faced that problem.If you use this in your AndroidManifest.xml file you can solve your problem <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> or your sdk version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your manifest file

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"></supports-screens>
```

Comment: And, before this, check your SDK version that you are compiling with. This attribute will only work API level 7 and up.